# Count consecutive duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table like so

```
ID     OrdID     Value
1      1          0     
2      2          0
3      1          1
4      2          1
5      1          1
6      2          0
7      1          0
8      2          0
9      2          1
10     1          0
11     2          0
```

I want to get the count of consecutive value where the value is 0.  Using the example above the result will be 3 (Rows 6, 7 and 8).  I am using sql server 2008 r2.

Comment: please explain in more detail. I'm not sure what you're referring to being consecutive and how. Are you referring to repeating sequences?

Comment: Wouldn't Rows 1 and 2 appear they have consecutive 0's....?

Comment: @BS123: i guess he only wants the max-count.

Comment: Yes max count. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am going to presume that `id` is unique and increasing.  You can get counts of consecutive values by using the different of row numbers.  The following counts all sequences:

```
select grp, value, min(id), max(id), count(*) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by value order by id)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp, value;
```

If you want the longest sequence of 0s:

```
select top 1 grp, value, min(id), max(id), count(*) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by value order by id)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp, value
having value = 0
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: nice. also a LAG function should work.. similar to these window functions.

Comment: Hi you are correct, the ID is increasing (primary key).  When I try your script in sql fiddle I get the following error. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.: select grp, value, min(id), max(id), count(*) as cnt from (select test.*, (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by value order by id) ) as grp from table test ) test group by grp, value

Comment: Okay there is a extra keyword Table after obtaining the value of grp. If you remove that it seems to work brilliantly.  Thank you Gordon Linoff.

Comment: @abeuwe . . . `table` is just meant to be the name of your table.

Answer (score 4):

A query using `not exists` to find consecutive 0s

```
select top 1 min(t2.id), max(t2.id), count(*)
from mytable t
join mytable t2 on t2.id <= t.id
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t3
    where t3.id between t2.id and t.id
    and t3.value <> 0
)
group by t.id
order by count(*) desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52989/3