# skip consecutive rows after specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

**Note:** I have a working query, but am looking for optimisations to use it on large tables.

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
id  session_id  value
1       5           7
2       5           1
3       5           1
4       5           12
5       5           1
6       5           1
7       5           1
8       6           7
9       6           1
10      6           3
11      6           1
12      7           7
13      8           1
14      8           2
15      8           3
```

I want the id's of all rows with value 1 with one exception:
skip groups with value 1 that directly follow a value 7 within the same session_id.

Basically I would look for groups of value 1 that directly follow a value 7, limited by the session_id, and ignore those groups. I then show all the remaining value 1 rows.

The desired output showing the id's:

```
5
6
7
11
13
```

I took some inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252235/count-consecutive-duplicate-values-in-sql) and ended up with this code:

```
declare @req_data table (
    id int primary key identity,
    session_id int,
    value int
)

insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (5, 7)
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (5, 1)  -- preceded by value 7 in same session, should be ignored
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (5, 1)  -- ignore this one too
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (5, 12)
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (5, 1)  -- preceded by value != 7, show this
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (5, 1)  -- show this too
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (5, 1)  -- show this too
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (6, 7)
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (6, 1)  -- preceded by value 7 in same session, should be ignored
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (6, 3)
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (6, 1)  -- preceded by value != 7, show this
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (7, 7)
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (8, 1)  -- new session_id, show this
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (8, 2)
insert into @req_data(session_id, value) values (8, 3)



select id
from (
    select session_id, id, max(skip) over (partition by grp) as 'skip'
    from (
        select tWithGroups.*,
            ( row_number() over (partition by session_id order by id) - row_number() over (partition by value order by id) ) as grp
        from (
            select session_id, id, value,
                case
                    when lag(value) over (partition by session_id order by session_id) = 7
                        then 1
                    else 0
                end as 'skip'
            from @req_data
        ) as  tWithGroups
    ) as tWithSkipField
    where tWithSkipField.value = 1
) as tYetAnotherOutput
where skip != 1
order by id
```

This gives the desired result, but with 4 select blocks I think it's way too inefficient to use on large tables.

Is there a cleaner, faster way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at LAG: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql You can look at the previous row.

Comment: They used `LAG` in the original query @Leonidas199x

Comment: I think this belongs on Code Review, not Stack Exchange.  It is working code.

Comment: @TabAlleman if it does not scale to a practical data volume, then I might still consider it as errant. Like, if your algorithm is O(n!) to sort an array, I wouldn't consider that "working". This code looks to be O(n^2) for an apparent O(n) task, and we should be interested in an efficient set-based solution to avoid writing custom loops in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CRow.id
FROM @req_data AS CRow
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM @req_data PRev WHERE PRev.Id < CRow.id  AND PRev.session_id = CRow.session_id AND  PRev.value <> 1 ) MaxPRow
LEFT JOIN @req_data AS PRow ON MaxPRow.id = PRow.id
WHERE CRow.value = 1 AND ISNULL(PRow.value,1) <> 7
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution with the lowest impact on the server. So far I haven't been able to find any gaps in the output, so that's good. :)
EDIT: Sorry, I got my comments the wrong way around..

Answer (score 2):

The following should work well for this.

```
WITH
    cte_ControlValue AS (
        SELECT 
            rd.id, rd.session_id, rd.value,
            ControlValue = ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinVal) OVER (PARTITION BY rd.session_id ORDER BY rd.id), 5, 4) AS INT), 999)
        FROM
            @req_data rd
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(rd.id AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(NULLIF(rd.value, 1) AS BINARY(4))) ) bv (BinVal)
        )
SELECT 
    cv.id, cv.session_id, cv.value
FROM
    cte_ControlValue cv
WHERE 
    cv.value = 1
    AND cv.ControlValue <> 7;
```

Results...

```
id          session_id  value
----------- ----------- -----------
5           5           1
6           5           1
7           5           1
11          6           1
13          8           1
```

Edit: How and why it works...
The basic premise is taken from [Itzik Ben-Gan's "The Last non NULL Puzzle"](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle).

Essentially, we are relying 2 different behaviors that most people don't usually think about...

1) NULL + anything = NULL.
2) You can CAST or CONVERT an INT into a fixed length BINARY data type and it will continue to sort as an INT (as opposed to sorting like a text string).

This is easier to see when the intermittent steps are added to the query in the CTE...

```
SELECT 
    rd.id, rd.session_id, rd.value, 
    bv.BinVal,
    SmearedBinVal = MAX(bv.BinVal) OVER (PARTITION BY rd.session_id ORDER BY rd.id),
    SecondHalfAsINT = CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinVal) OVER (PARTITION BY rd.session_id ORDER BY rd.id), 5, 4) AS INT),
    ControlValue = ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinVal) OVER (PARTITION BY rd.session_id ORDER BY rd.id), 5, 4) AS INT), 999)
FROM
    #req_data rd
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(rd.id AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(NULLIF(rd.value, 1) AS BINARY(4))) ) bv (BinVal)
```

Results...

```
id          session_id  value       BinVal             SmearedBinVal      SecondHalfAsINT ControlValue
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------ ------------------ --------------- ------------
1           5           7           0x0000000100000007 0x0000000100000007 7               7
2           5           1           NULL               0x0000000100000007 7               7
3           5           1           NULL               0x0000000100000007 7               7
4           5           12          0x000000040000000C 0x000000040000000C 12              12
5           5           1           NULL               0x000000040000000C 12              12
6           5           1           NULL               0x000000040000000C 12              12
7           5           1           NULL               0x000000040000000C 12              12
8           6           7           0x0000000800000007 0x0000000800000007 7               7
9           6           1           NULL               0x0000000800000007 7               7
10          6           3           0x0000000A00000003 0x0000000A00000003 3               3
11          6           1           NULL               0x0000000A00000003 3               3
12          7           7           0x0000000C00000007 0x0000000C00000007 7               7
13          8           1           NULL               NULL               NULL            999
14          8           2           0x0000000E00000002 0x0000000E00000002 2               2
15          8           3           0x0000000F00000003 0x0000000F00000003 3               3
```

Looking at the BinVal column, we see an 8 byte hex value for all non-[value] = 1 rows and NULLS where [value] = 1... The 1st 4 bytes are the Id (used for ordering) and the 2nd 4 bytes are [value] (used to set the "previous non-1 value" or set the whole thing to NULL.

The 2nd step is to "smear" the non-NULL values into the NULLs using the window framed MAX function, partitioned by session_id and ordered by id.

The 3rd step is to parse out the last 4 bytes and convert them back to an INT data type (SecondHalfAsINT) and deal with any nulls that result from not having any non-1 preceding value (ControlValue).

Since we can't reference a windowed function in the WHERE clause, we have to throw the query into a CTE (a derived table would work just as well) so that we can use the new ControlValue in the where clause.

Comment: This is a clever solution, but it really needs an explanation.

Comment: This is a variation of Itzik Ben-Gan's solution to the Last non-NULL puzzle. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle...

In this case the Idead is, we want all rows with a [value] = 1 but only if the preceding non-1 value isn't = 7... So, by treating the [value] = 1 as nulls, we can use Itzik's method to get the "last non-null" value... Once we have that, the final where clause become really easy to write. I'll go ahead and update the answer a better explanation as well.

Comment: A clever solution with a very helpful explanation, thanks. Performance-wise it seems to be in second place, but I'm no expert at measuring that. (I used "SET STATISTICS TIME ON" and "SET STATISTICS IO ON" to get some stats)

Comment: I'd be interest in seeing your test. Using a #temp table in place of a @table variable, so that statics can be created... with the original test data and no additional indexes. I'm coming up with the following... binary concat: total scan count = 20; total logical reads = 93; cpu time = 0 elapsed time = 00:00:00.001 /// gaps & islands: total scan count = 23; total logical reads = 156; cpu time = 0; elapsed time = 00:00:00.046

Comment: adding a covering nonclustered index on session_id & id removes the sort (77% of the plan cost) from the binary concat solution, making it ~ 5 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
select id, session_id, value,
          coalesce(sum(case when value <> 1 then 1 end) 
                   over (partition by session_id order by id), 0) as grp
from @req_data
```

to get:

```
id  session_id  value   grp
----------------------------
1   5           7       1
2   5           1       1
3   5           1       1
4   5           12      2
5   5           1       2
6   5           1       2
7   5           1       2
8   6           7       1
9   6           1       1
10  6           3       2
11  6           1       2
12  7           7       1
13  8           1       0
14  8           2       1
15  8           3       2
```

So, this query detects islands of consecutive `1` records that belong to the same *group*, as specified by the *first* preceding row with `value <> 1`.

You can use a window function once more to detect all `7` islands. If you wrap this in a second cte, then you can finally get the desired result by filtering out all `7` islands:

```
;with session_islands as (
   select id, session_id, value,
          coalesce(sum(case when value <> 1 then 1 end) 
                   over (partition by session_id order by id), 0) as grp
   from @req_data
), islands_with_7 as (
   select id, grp, value,
          count(case when value = 7 then 1 end) 
          over (partition by session_id, grp) as cnt_7
   from session_islands
)
select id 
from islands_with_7
where cnt_7 = 0 and value = 1
```

Comment: @NicoKempe Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: This works, though it takes about 15ms time on a table with 1000 records. For comparison, other scripts take 3-12ms. According to the actual execution plan, there are two sort actions taking 32% each.
EDIT: Sorry, I got my comments the wrong way around..